# data manipulation of paginator array in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have `Task` model which has date saved as timestamp, when i paginate i wan't to be displayed as "Today", "Tomorrow", "Next Week", etc. I made custom function `niceDate_hr($date)` that returns string I need. But i have problem with modifying array that paginator makes. My current code is:

```
    $this->loadModel('Task');
    $this->Task->create();
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions' => array('Task.user_id' => $user['ID']),
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => array('Task.date' => 'desc')
    );
    $tasks = $this->Paginator->paginate('Task');
    $ctask = new TasksController;
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $task['Task']['date'] = $ctask->niceDate_hr($task['Task']['date']);
    }
    $this -> set('tasks', $tasks);
```

P.S. Forgive me about any grammar and spelling errors.

Comment: Can you explain to us what you are expecting to happen, what's currently happening? Maybe a set of expected output and actual output?

Comment: @nbokmans my output was with timestamp and expected was string as returned value of `niceDate_hr($task['Task']['date'])` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're violating the [MVC](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html) pattern. **Don't do  that:** `$ctask = new TasksController;` There is plenty of information with details around why this is wrong. Only the dispatcher should instantiate the controller and there should be always just one controller instance. You never instantiate controllers. Except in tests.

Further you're doing data manipulation which should, when it is required, happen in the model layer, *not* in the controller. But you want to format output, which should happen in the *view* layer.

The proper implementation would be to move your custom method, which is as well not following the conventions (should be named camel cased), [in a helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html) and use it in your view.

```
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
       echo $this->MyFancyHelper->niceDateHr($task['Task']['date']);
}
```

I don't know how you format your date but CakePHP comes with a time helper that allows formatting as well.

Comment: thanks fo the help, I use `TaskController` with respective view for CRUD but i need to output latest few task on "overview" page, on this page I used instances of the other controllers, what is best woraround on that?

Comment: also I use camelCase but for localization I use snake_case like testFunction_en() because other code was like that and I continued for consistency

Comment: Get the data through the assocs and set it to the view. The models are thought to deliver the data *not* controllers. language suffixed methods are broken by design. Either pass the language as argument to a *single* method or find another way of doing it. This just hard codes languages into the code which is not good.